# How to show that the union of two negative sets is a negative set given a signed measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

This questions seems to be fairly easy but I got stuck.

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure with domain $\Sigma$. We define a measurable set $E$ as negative with respect to $\mu$ if $\mu(E\,\cap\, A)\leq0$ for any measurable set $A$. In the book I'm reading it is said that the union of two negative sets is a negative set.

To show this I tried to rewrite the union as:

$\mu(E\, \cup\, F) = \mu(E) + \mu(F) - \mu(E\, \cap\, F)$,

where $E$ and $F$ are negative sets, which I know holds when $\mu$ is a probability measure. But I'm not sure if the previous equality is justified for signed measures in general (is it?). Even if it is justified we still need to show that $\mu(E) + \mu(F) \leq \mu(E\, \cap\, F)$, considering $\mu(E\, \cap\, F)\leq0$ and thus $-\mu(E\, \cap\, F)\geq0$.

Comment: You should use the definition of *negative sets*. For example, you will have to prove that for any measurable set $A$, $$\mu(A \cap (E\cup F) ) \le 0$$ so how will you decompose $\mu(A \cap (E\cup F) ) $ into the form $\mu(B \cap E) +\mu( C \cap F)$ to you use the properties of negative. sets $E$,$F$?

Comment: $\mu[A\cap(E\cup F)] = \mu[A\cap(E\cup F)\cap F] + \mu[A\cap(E\cup F)\cap F^C] = \mu[A \cap F] + \mu[(A \cap F^C) \cap E]$. Because it can be shown that the complement of a measurable set is measurable and the intersection of measurable sets is measurable, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Yeah, that's just it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E,F$ are negative with respect to $\mu$, and $A$ is a measurable set, then
$$
(E\cup F)\cap A
=
\Bigl(E\cap (F'\cap A)\Bigr)
\;
\cup
\;
\Bigl(F\cap (E'\cap A)\Bigr)
\;
\cup
\;
\Bigl(E\cap (F\cap A)\Bigr)
\;
$$
which is a disjoint union of $3$ sets, each with nonpositive measure.